# Does elasticsearch have the equivalent of 'cores' like in solr?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

I'm eyeballing the use of ElasticSearch or solr for 'jailed' search results. By jailed I want to keep sets of data apart for security purposes, etc.

As far as I can tell, this is possible by use of solr's multi core configuration - is there a way to isolate indexes/data in an efficient 'instancing' manner using ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ElasticSearch, you can separate data by indexing into separate indices, then limiting your query to a particular index.

For example, if you have two indices, 'foo' and 'bar' running:

```
% curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_search?q=*:*
```

will search the entire cluster, while:

```
% curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/foo/_search?q=*:*
```

will search only the 'foo' index.

You can also separate data by types, if you create an index 'test' with the following:

```
% curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test -d '{
    "mappings" : {
        "type1" : {
            "_source" : { "enabled" : false },
            "properties" : {
                "field1" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
            }
        },
        "type2" : {
            "_source" : { "enabled" : false },
            "properties" : {
                "field1" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

You can search only the 'type1' documents by specifying the type with the query:

```
% curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/test/type1/_search?q=*:*
```

Comment: So say I had multiple customers; a 'type' could be their customer/org id in this context?

Comment: @thinice yes, you could choose to separate each customer into a type. Or, depending on your configuration and number of customers, you could choose to separate each customer into a separate index.

Comment: The important difference in the two approaches, which you should bother about is, in case of multiple types with in one index, ES will put it into the same set of shards. In the other case of having multiple indices, there will be a different set of shards. The difference will impact the security and search performance.

Comment: I will recommend go with first approach, especially when u want to achieve multi tenancy.

Comment: How would one go about preventing Tenant1 (e.g with his index being at `http://localhost:9200/tenant1/_search?q=*:*`) from accessing the index of tenant2 at `http://localhost:9200/tenant2/_search?q=*:*`?